# City dropdown at checkout magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout

I use magento 2.0.7 is it possible to custom the checkout page city field(text) to dropdown list?

Comment: http://oyenetwork.com/articles/magento2-devliery-date-module-creation-from-scratch/ this explains how to add delivery date in checkout process, you can use same method to add city drop down. Hope that helps

Answer (score 9):

Yes.

The easiest would be to add a new entity where the values for your cities are stored. In the frontend, just **change the input type to dropdown** and load the list of cities. When a user selects a field from the dropdown, **store the text value** (as it is now). You could even do a check if the selected city is a valid one from your city list before storing the data.
This way you don't have to change a lot.

A more advanced approach (if needed) would be to also add relations to the `directory_country` and/or `directory_country_region` tables to only show cities which belong to the specific country or region selected in the checkout.

Comment: Can you please share screen of the table as i am not finding any city field these tables

Answer (score 3):

for the sesion of estimate shipping and Tax of magento you will need overwrite of the class \Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\LayoutProcessor.

```
 $elements = [
        'city' => [
            'visible' => true,
            'formElement' => 'select',
            'label' => __('City'),
            'value' =>  '',
            'options' => array_option(),
        ],
```

[image]

Comment: can you provide tutorial  code/github link for this

Comment: Can you please provide a code here