# How can I change City (text) to Select base on State in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

City field is normally required text field in magento 2. I like to change it into select field like as country and state relationship.

Country>State>City

Comment: you can find answer here , https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/121659/31830