# Make City as dropdown list checkout

Tags: magento2, checkout, drop-downs, delivery

I am using WebShopApps MatrixRates with Magento 2.2.3 to manage delivery rates per destination city, It works fine however I want to make "City" as a dropdown list to avoid any misspelling because this will impact delivery costs.

Thank You.

Comment: Have a look at this https://codecanyon.net/item/magento-city-and-region-manager/17911995. NOT TESTED

Comment: Thanks @krybbio but price must change according to City,

Comment: please see this link, https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/121659/31830 it will help you

Comment: thanks @zexperto-WISAMHAKIM but this is incomplet