# Magento2 : How to add city field to dropdown on checkout page?

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods

I want add city drop-down in checkout page without any extension. I have tried some reference link for adding city dropdown but it is adding ony on cart page on estimate section.
I want to add in checkout page. kindly help me if anyone have an idea for that.

Comment: You can check the extension for this given on the GIT :
https://github.com/EaDesgin/Magento2-City-Dropdown

Comment: I have already tried it, and mentioned in my query description that I want to do without any extension. Can you help me without this extension please?

Comment: @RaviVarma, try this answer it already given: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/120691/city-dropdown-at-checkout-magento-2/121659#121659

Comment: i try to use this extension 

https://github.com/EaDesgin/Magento2-City-Dropdown#magento-2-city-dropdown

But there are errors like Specified invalid parent id (Eadesigndev_Eacore::eadesign)

Answer (score 0):

Here are the few free extensions for Magento 2 city Dropdwon

> https://packagist.org/packages/php-cuong/magento2-city-dropdown
>
> https://github.com/EaDesgin/Magento2-City-Dropdown

If you are not willing to use any extension then you will need to overwrite this file `vendor\magento\module-checkout\Block\Cart\LayoutProcessor.php` and replace the process function with this one. Option array is empty in below code

```
public function process($jsLayout)
{
    $elements = [
        'city' => [
        'visible' => true,
        'formElement' => 'select',
        'label' => __('City'),
        'value' =>  '',
        'options' => array_option(),
        ],
        'country_id' => [
            'visible' => true,
            'formElement' => 'select',
            'label' => __('Country'),
            'options' => [],
            'value' => null
        ],
        'region_id' => [
            'visible' => true,
            'formElement' => 'select',
            'label' => __('State/Province'),
            'options' => [],
            'value' => null
        ],
        'postcode' => [
            'visible' => true,
            'formElement' => 'input',
            'label' => __('Zip/Postal Code'),
            'value' => null
        ]
    ];

    if (!isset($jsLayout['components']['checkoutProvider']['dictionaries'])) {
        $jsLayout['components']['checkoutProvider']['dictionaries'] = [
            'country_id' => $this->countryCollection->loadByStore()->setForegroundCountries(
                $this->topDestinationCountries->getTopDestinations()
            )->toOptionArray(),
            'region_id' => $this->regionCollection->addAllowedCountriesFilter()->toOptionArray(),
        ];
    }
    if (isset($jsLayout['components']['block-summary']['children']['block-shipping']['children']
        ['address-fieldsets']['children'])
    ) {
        $fieldSetPointer = &$jsLayout['components']['block-summary']['children']['block-shipping']
        ['children']['address-fieldsets']['children'];
        $fieldSetPointer = $this->merger->merge($elements, 'checkoutProvider', 'shippingAddress', $fieldSetPointer);
        $fieldSetPointer['region_id']['config']['skipValidation'] = true;
    }
    return $jsLayout;
}
```

There should be custom option array for cities in array options

**I hope this will help**

Comment: Working fine but your suggestion works at estimate shipping at cart page, Not at checkout page. I think op also mentioned that checkout page not cart page. If you have any suggestion for checkout page specially for shipping address ? Thanks for cart page solution! :D